# Chrome console debug is broken?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, console, inspector

With the update of Chrome to version 2.3 I have the following problem. When ik debug something like

```
console.log($('canvas'))
```

I normally got some code back in the console (in this case html) which I could hover on, so the object was highlighted in the HTML. Now I got this:

```
[<canvas>, <canvas>, <canvas>, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: #document, selector: "canvas"]
```

Is there a setting where it can be changed back, so I get the normal html with hover in the HTML page?

Comment: It's returning an array of `canvas` elements. Either supply an index to the array or select a specific one using an `id` in the selector.

Comment: Being specific works kind of; console.log($('canvas')[0]); for example gives me back what I want: <canvas id="layer2"> which is hoverable. But when I do this console.log($('#layer1')); I get: [context: #document, selector: "#layer2"]

Comment: I too noticed this issue today. There is also a ruler that appears on the left and top of the console screen.

Comment: I found this [link](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/10/do-more-with-chrome-developer-tools.html) detailing some of the updates.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is an extension of `Array`, or speaking on javascript's language -- JQuery's prototype is Array. So when you `$('canvas')`'ing it takes a collection of document elements. The solution is to debug elements itself, using code like:

```
console.debug($('canvas')[0]); // or other index if there is more than one elements is collected
```

Comment: I dont't think it has anything to do with Jquery of Javascript. This morning everything worked fine until the automatic update of Chrome to version 23.0.1271.64 (mac). I used to console.log every jquery, javascript object so it became accessable and hoverable in the console. Now its broken for me, has anyone else this problem or is there a setting which can be reverted?

Comment: Consider to use Firebug (Firefox's extension), it is more advanced and mature. Try it, it's all free ;)

Comment: The `console.debug($(selector)[0]);` worked for me. Now if I want to display an array of elements, I have to iterate over them, `$.each($(selector), function() { console.log($(this)[0])' })` as opposed to just `console.log($(selector));`. Oh well. Just something to note. I like Chrome developer tools better than Firebug since you can edit DOM objects directly in the tools.